# What is Simpler Way to Write Code That Sums Up Length of Strings including nulls and undefineds in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to add some defensive coding to the following check.  I have 3 strings and I want to know if any of them have anything in them (for my purposes, null or undefined means they do not have anything in them).

```
if (twitterUrl.length + facebookUrl.length + linkedInUrl.length > 0) {
```

This works, but feels like very bulky. I use TypeScript and not sure if there is anything there that can help me with this.

```
    if ((twitterUrl ? twitterUrl.length : 0) +
        (facebookUrl ? facebookUrl.length : 0) +
        (linkedInUrl ? linkedInUrl.length : 0) > 0) {
```

Comment: `if (twitterUrl || facebookUrl || linkedInUrl) { ... }`

Comment: @Andreas , if any of them are empty strings, doesn't this evaluate to true?

Comment: It evaluates to true when any of them is not a falsy value (like a non-empty string) as requested: _"I want to know if any of them have anything in them"_ (see the answer from [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53897363/402037) for an explanation when it get's undeleted)

Comment: @Andreas , i clarified.  Am I correct in assuming that in JavaScript a null and undefined string both resolve to false? I checked that at node prompt and that seems to be the case

Comment: You're right. Check T.J.s answer. He's listed all _"falsy"_ values which evaluate to `false`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the fact that empty strings are *falsy*¹. If you know they'll be strings or `null` or `undefined` and you don't need to worry about strings with just whitespace in them (`"   "` is truthy¹), then:

```
if (twitterUrl || facebookUrl || linkedInUrl) {
```

If you need to worry about trimming, then a helper function is probably in order:

```
function present(s) {
    return s && (typeof s !== "string" || s.trim());
}
```

and

```
if (present(twitterUrl) || present(facebookUrl) || present(linkedInUrl)) {
```

or

```
if ([twitterUrl, facebookUrl, linkedInUrl].some(present)) {
```

---

¹ *falsy* and *truthy*: When you use a value in a condition (like an `if`), JavaScript will implicitly coerce the value to a boolean. A value that coerces to `false` is *falsy*; one that coerces to `true` is *truthy*. The falsy values are `""`, `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `NaN`, and of course, `false`. All other values (including `" "`) are *truthy*.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this, normal if statement also works

```
const socialLinks = [twitterUrl, facebookUrl, linkedInUrl];

const hasSomething = socialLinks.some(social => social);
```

Here is falsy value like null, undefined, '' and etc., https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

if `social` are empty string(`''`)  or `null` or `undefined` then it's return `false`. We omitted `return` keyword because arrow function has implicit return behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a function as the following one:

```
function getLength(s){
   if(typeof s !== "string") return 0;
   return s.length;
}
```

and then use it like below:

```
if (getLength(twitterUrl) > 0 || getLenght(facebookUrr) > 0 || getLength(linkedInUrl){
    // code
}
```

Essentially, `getLength` check if the value you pass when you call the function is a string and if so it returns its length. Otherwise, it returns 0. So in order to achieve that you want, (*I want to know if any of them have anything in them*), you have to check one by one the strings you have, if the first string has a length greater than zero, there isn't any need to continue the check for the other two strings. Otherwise you call the function on the second string and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution using [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), which checks whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

```js
var twitterUrl, facebookUrl, linkedInUrl;
linkedInUrl = 'nonEmpty';
result = [twitterUrl, facebookUrl, linkedInUrl].some(arrVal => arrVal);

console.log(result);
```